# putting zenmap output onto excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, output, spreadsheet, nmap

I've been using nmap to scan my network in order to remediate the heartbleed vulnerability if needed. I am using the zenmap interface to view results but I can't figure out how to open results in an excel file in a way that makes sense. I have tried saving the output as both xml and text (.nmap) and then opening it in excel but it is always a disaster. The xml ouput doesnt offer as much information and the text output is extremely messy. Is there a better way to save results in an easy to read format, so it can be shared with less technical folks?
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

[Nmap's XML output](http://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html) actually contains *more* information than the text output. If you are looking for the output of the [`ssl-heartbleed`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-heartbleed.html) NSE script, then you can find it in the `script[@id='ssl-heartbleed']/@output` attribute. In versions of Nmap after 6.49BETA1, the `script` element will also have nested elements that can be directly queried instead of parsing the text output.

As for getting the information into Excel, there are lots of resources around the Internet for parsing Nmap's XML output with PowerShell. [Here's one from SANS](https://cyber-defense.sans.org/blog/2009/06/11/powershell-script-to-parse-nmap-xml-output). PowerShell also has great [integration with Excel](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/10/powershell-and-excel-fast-safe-and-reliable.aspx) so you can build a spreadsheet from the parsed objects. I suppose if you had problems with this, you could ask a more specific question and tag it with [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).